# Enum with custom setter to track my program's state

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to store the state of my program, in particular whether it's in online/offline mode as well as what type of search was last run. Based on those two factors I want to modify parts of my program (e.g. the GUI).

To me it makes the most sense to store these states as `enums`. The setter can then call a method when the values get changed.

Edit: Fixed my solution based on the answers I got from @Icemanind and @Rahul:

```
namespace Foo
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // define enum:
    public enum OnlineState
    {
        Online,
        Offline
    };

    // variable that the OnlineState is stored in:
    public OnlineState appOnlineState;

    // custom setter/getter:
    public OnlineState AppOnlineState
    {
        get
        {
            return appOnlineState;
        }
        set
        {
            OnlineStateValueChanged(value);
            appOnlineState = value;
        }
    }

    // ValueChanged-method:
    void OnlineStateValueChanged(OnlineState OS)
    {
        if (OS == OnlineState.Online)
        {
            // do stuff here
            // I'm leaving some of my code as an example
            if (Settings.Default.ColorblindMode == true)
            {
                Label_Status.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
                StatusBar_Grid.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
            }
            else if (Settings.Default.ColorblindMode == false)
            {
                Label_Status.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
                StatusBar_Grid.Background = Brushes.Green;
            }
            Label_Status.Content = "Online";

            // activate certain MenuItems
            ActivateMenuItem(Menu_Intranet);
            ActivateMenuItem(Menu_SAP);
        }
        else if (OS == OnlineState.Offline)
        {
            // do stuff here
            // I'm leaving some of my code as an example
            if (Settings.Default.ColorblindMode == true)
            {
                Label_Status.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;
                StatusBar_Grid.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            }
            else if (Settings.Default.ColorblindMode == false)
            {
                Label_Status.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                StatusBar_Grid.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
            Label_Status.Content = "Offline";

            // deactivate MenuItems
            DeactivateMenuItem(Menu_Intranet);
            DeactivateMenuItem(Menu_SAP);
        }
        else
        {
            // this should not happen
            MessageBox.Show("There has been a problem with the online/offline check.","Warning",MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now I can set the `OnlineState` via `AppOnlineState = OnlineState.Online;` and `AppOnlineState = OnlineState.Offline;`.

To check ("get") the `OnlineState` I can check the value of `AppOnlineState` which is going to return `Online` or `Offline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because `OnlineState` really isn't part of `State`. However `OS` is a class that is part of `State` and `OnlineState` is part of `OS`. I think this is what you want:

```
State.OS.AppOnlineState = State.OnlineState.Online;
```

Also, as a side note, I don't know what it is you're creating, but usually on/off states are part of the instance, not static. Think of it as a real world thing. When I turn my computer off, it doesn't shut off *every* computer in the world. It only shuts off my computer. My instance of a computer.

Comment: Oh boy, I went through a lot of iterations trying out different people's solutions and ended up posting a weird mix. My apologies. What you posted works though, thank you!   

Do I need to create another class inside `State` that handles `SearchState` similar to how `OS` handles `OnlineState`?   

As for the side note, it's a single instance app so I guess it does not matter? I need to grey out some things when I have no network connection for example.

Comment: @RD - I don't think you need to mess with `SearchState`, but I would make them consistent. So either make another class for `SearchState` or move `OnlineState` outside of it's own class.

Comment: I definitely want to make things consistent, I just don't know how I can call `SearchState`'s setter so `SearchStateValueChanged();` is called.
I tried `static State.SearchState _ss = new State.SearchState();` and then `_ss = State.SearchState.material;` which definitely set the value but not via `AppOnlineState`.

Comment: @RD - You need to make `SearchStateValueChanged()` static. Change` public void SearchStateValueChanged()` to ` public static void SearchStateValueChanged()` and you should be able to call it.

Answer (score 0):

The below line

```
static State.OnlineState _os = new State.OnlineState();
```

Should be

```
State.OnlineState _os = State.OnlineState.online;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer!
This gives me a compiler error CS0572:
'OnlineState' : cannot reference a type through an expression; try 'State.OnlineState' instead.

Comment: @RD, mistake ... you don' need any instantiation since that's as well a type. See edit in answer

Comment: using

    `State.OnlineState _os = State.OnlineState.online;`

still leads to the problem that my program claims `_os` does not exist even in the very next line:

error CS0103: The name '_os' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @RD, post the code as how you are accessing it. Edit your post and include that

Comment: Uh, yeah, I tried accessing it right in the beginning of `public partial class MainWindow : Window` -.- Works within methods.